# Trying to create notification box when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, interface

I have been having some trouble in creating a simple notification box. Basically the objective here when I click the submit button `input type=button` it will display a simple notification box like this.

[image]
http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/onclick_zps124dc641.png

I have been told a plugin is not necessary for this kind of thing. I'm still in the process of learning Javascript and would like to ask for some advice on how i can obtain this kind of result.

I have tried using alert but it seems it cannot be styled and I need to use jquery instead.

Comment: I can not see your image! check your link please!

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery ui dialog, if you're planing to use jquery. Have look: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a decent walkthrough as well as the code to do what you are looking for without using plugins. These are often called "modal dialogs".

http://javascript.about.com/library/blmodald2.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the box using css and show/hide it using jquery. Once you have the css for the box applied to say a class named .box

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    border:2px solid red;
    padding:10px;
}
.box .title {
    float:left;
}
.box .close {
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.box .content {
    margin-top:10px;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
#dialog {
    display:none;
}
```

So now you have the box with the following :

```
<div class="box" id="dialog">
    <div class="title">Almost there</div>
    <div class="close">X</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="content">Thank you for subscribing....</div>
</div>
<button id="showdialog">Show</button> <!--This is trigger for the dialog-->
```

Now let's keep the box hidden on load

```
#dialog{
display:none;
}
```

So we trigger the dialog to be shown when the button is clicked

```
$("#showdialog").click(function () {
    $(".box").show();
});
$(".box .close").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().hide(); //When the x button is clicked, the dialog is hidden
})
```

This will show/hide the dialog in place. If you want to center it, or something, use static positioning

```
#dialog {

    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    left:20%;
    top:20%;
}
```

JSFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/zbaNe/

Or you can use a premade dialog plugin like jquery ui dialog(or bootstrap alerts)

Try noty.js , I highly recommend it